# sort blocks in tabular file

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I would like to sort file A based in column 1 with the blank lines preserved and occurrence of value from top to bottom.

I have a tabular file A:

```
seq1 5 15  
seq1 20 34  

seq1 50 48  
seq1 45 36  

seq2 17 20  

seq1 55 75  
seq1 80 84  

seq2 30 48  
seq2 55 66

seq3 27 40
```

I would like to get an output as follows:

```
seq1 5 15  
seq1 20 34  

seq1 50 48  
seq1 45 36  

seq1 55 75  
seq1 80 84 

seq2 17 20  

seq2 30 48  
seq2 55 66

seq3 27 40
```

The Blank lines should be preserved.

I have tried using `sort` but it removes blank lines and doesn't maintain the order from top to bottom.

```
sort -k1,1 fileA.txt
```

Could anyone point what am I missing here?

Many thanks.

Comment: `sort` sorts lines in a file. That's all it does. You're looking for something that sorts blocks of text. `sort` cannot do that as it's line-based but `awk` can since awk is record-based instead of line-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for sorting and 2D arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk         
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
{ rec[$1][++cnt[$1]] = $0 }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (key in rec) {
        for (nr=1; nr <= cnt[key]; nr++) {
            print rec[key][nr]
        }
    }
}
$ 
$ gawk -f tst.awk file
seq1 5 15
seq1 20 34

seq1 50 48
seq1 45 36

seq1 55 75
seq1 80 84

seq2 17 20

seq2 30 48
seq2 55 66

seq3 27 40
```

You'll need gawk version 4.0 at least.

For numeric ordering:

```
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
{ key=gensub(/^[^[:digit:]]+/,"","",$1); rec[key][++cnt[key]] = $0 }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (key in rec) {
        for (nr=1; nr <= cnt[key]; nr++) {
            print rec[key][nr]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On awk 3.1 this would work `awk -vRS= '{a[$0]}END{ORS="\n\n";x=asorti(a);for(i=1;i<=x;i++)print a[i]}' file`

Comment: Many thanks. Both gawk and awk works great. Can I sort them in numeric order like seq1, seq2, seq3 ........ instead of seq1, seq11, seq2, seq222.....?

Comment: Yes, I added an example of that. This solution ONLY works in gawk, not any other awk.

Comment: The blank lines between blocks contain 3 spaces instead of only one space. How can I remove extra space. I want only one space blank line.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Update your question to provide corrected input if what you have posted already is wrong,